# Python multiprocessing multiple iterations

Tags: python

I am trying to use multiprocessing to speed up my data processing. I am working on a machine with 6 Cores, so I want to iterate through a table of 12 million rows, and for each of these rows I iterate through several time steps doing a calculation (executing a function).

This line I would like to split up that it runs in parallel on different cores:
test = [rowiteration(i, output, ini_cols, cols) for i in a]  # this should run in parallel

I tried something with
from multiprocessing import Pool
but I did not manage to pass the arguments of the function and the iterator.
I would appreciate any idea. I am new to Python.

This is what i have:

````
import pyreadr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import functools
from pathlib import Path


def read_data():
    current_path = os.getcwd()
    myfile = os.path.join(str(Path(current_path).parents[0]), 'dummy.RData')
    result = pyreadr.read_r(myfile)
    pc = result["pc"]
    u = result["u"]
    return pc, u


# add one column per time
def prepare_output_structure(pc):
    ini_cols = pc.columns
    pc = pc.reindex(columns=[*pc.columns, *np.arange(0, 11), 'cat'], fill_value=0)
    pc.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
    # print(pc.columns, pc.shape, pc.dtypes)
    return pc, ini_cols


def conjunction(*conditions):
    return functools.reduce(np.logical_and, conditions)


def timeloop(t_final: int, count_final: int, tipo):
    if tipo == 'A':
        count_ini = 35
    else:  # B:
        count_ini = 30

    yy_list = []
    for t in np.arange(0, 11):
        yy = ((count_final - count_ini) / t_final) * t + count_ini
        yy_list.append(int(yy))
    return yy_list


def rowiteration(i, output, ini_cols, cols):
    c_2: bool = pc.loc[i, 'tipo'] == u.iloc[:, 0].str[:1]  # first character of category e.g. 'A1'
    c_5: bool = pc.loc[i, 't_final'] >= u.iloc[:, 1]  # t_min (u)
    c_6: bool = pc.loc[i, 't_final'] <= (u.iloc[:, 2])  # t_max (u)
    pc.loc[i, 'cat'] = u[conjunction(c_2, c_5, c_6)].iloc[0, 0]
    pc.iloc[i, (0 + (len(ini_cols))+1):(10 + (len(ini_cols))+2)] = timeloop(int(pc.loc[i, 't_final']), int(pc.loc[i, 'count_final']), pc.loc[i, 'tipo'])
    out = pd.DataFrame(pc.iloc[i, :])
    out = pd.DataFrame(out.transpose(), columns=cols)
    output = output.append(out.iloc[0, :])
    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()


    pc, u = read_data()
    nrowpc = len(pc.index)
    a = np.arange(0, nrowpc)  # filas tabla pc
    # print(a, nrowpc, len(pc.index))
    pc, ini_cols = prepare_output_structure(pc)
    cols = pc.columns
    output = pd.DataFrame()

    test = [rowiteration(i, output, ini_cols, cols) for i in a]  # this should run in parallel
    pc2 = pd.concat(test, ignore_index=True)
    pc2 = pc2.iloc[:, np.r_[5, (len(ini_cols)+1):(len(pc2.columns))]]
    print(pc2.head)


    elapsed_time_secs = time.time() - start_time
    msg = "Execution took: %s secs (Wall clock time)" % timedelta(milliseconds=elapsed_time_secs)
    print(msg)```
````

Comment: Just so you know, most of the time multiprocessing won't speedup your computation because of the GIL(Global Interpreter Lock), if you're using structured data i recommand using dask dataframe, which should do the trick.

Comment: @Tbaki I think you are referring to mutithreading. Multiprocessing could speed up because GIL would only limit to one interpreter per process.

Comment: @ZLi I think you're right, i just looked it up, process are more memory heavy but bypass the GIL.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `[rowiteration(i, output, ini_cols, cols) for i in a]` with:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

n_cpu = 10  # put in the number of threads of cpu
with Pool(processes=n_cpu) as pool:
     ret = pool.starmap(rowiteration,
                        [(i, output, ini_cols, cols) for i in a])
```

Comment: That works! I only need to put the tables as arguments as well as: pool.starmap(rowiteration, [(i, pc, u, output, ini_cols, cols) for i in a]) Thank you very much!

Comment: I was wondering why it does not recognize the tables pc and u when using multiprocessing?

Comment: What do you mean by not recognize?

Comment: I noticed a speed up for small datasets, but for large datasets it even slows down. I guess that it is because pool needs to transfer the data for each process, so it loads the data pc through which I do the row iteration each time. The larger pc, the slower the performance. I read suggestions to chunk pc and read in only one chunk per process. Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: If I put just this [rowiteration(i, output, ini_cols, cols) for i in a] in the pool.starmap, I get the following error (If I put [(i, pc, u, output, ini_cols, cols) for i in a] it works.):

multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "\pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "bla.py", line 52, in rowiteration
    c_2: bool = pc.loc[i, 'tipo'] == u.iloc[:, 0].str[:1] 
NameError: name 'pc' is not defined
"""

Comment: regarding the NameError: yes you have to either put variable as gloabl variable (above if name == main) or pass them directly into the function. Regarding split data into chunks, just manually slice them.

Comment: Thank you @Z Li ! I am still testing (and learning)... If I put the variable above name == main I don't need to pass them directly into the function. The script runs in both manners, but it behaves different in term of processing. Defining the variables as global I run into memory error (RAM) when n_cpu is larger than 6. In contrast passing the variables directly to the function it works also with n_cpu>6. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Another question (sorry I am really a newbee), If my machine has 6 processors, each with 2 cores and 2 logical processors, so maximal n_cpu in the script can be 12, right? Maybe its not convenient to put the maximum, but only 10?

Comment: I am only guessing, that making it global would copy the variable double the times than passing them into the function. And yes the max is 12 and I would suggest sth like 10.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that I think solves the problem and that only sends what is necessary to the worker processes. I haven't tested this as is (which would be difficult without the data your code reads in) but this is basic idea:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

p = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())

# Note that you already define the static cols and ini_cols
# in global scope so you don't need to pass them to the Pool.

# ... Other functions you've defined ...

def rowiteration(row):
    c_2: bool = row['tipo'] == u.iloc[:, 0].str[:1]
    c_5: bool = row['t_final'] >= u.iloc[:, 1]
    c_6: bool = row['t_final'] <= (u.iloc[:, 2])
    row['cat'] = u[conjunction(c_2, c_5, c_6)].iloc[0, 0]
    row[(0 + (len(ini_cols))+1):(10 + (len(ini_cols))+2)] = timeloop(int(row['t_final']), int(row['count_final']), row['tipo'])
    return row

out = []
for row in p.imap_unordered(rowiteration, [r for _, r in pc.iterrows()]):
    row.index = cols
    out.append(cols)

pc2 = pd.DataFrame(out, ignore_index=True)
```